# dom elements not re-rendering when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a simple app that queries an api that returns a list of books when you search by title. I am adding the option to sort the search results.

When a user searches for a title, eg 'harry potter', the app stores an array of books in state and renders the results.

When a user then selects the option to sort (eg by title), my array of books in state is correctly being sorted and updated, but the old unsorted books are the ones shown.
Notably, if I then select to sort by date, this time I am seeing sorted books being displayed by it's the books sorted by title not date!

And also, at all times, the value of my books array is correctly sorted, but the books being displayed are not (it's essentially the previous state of books which is being rendered).
This is observable if you keep switching between title and sort, the app will update, but the results will be sorted by title when you try to sort by date and vice versa.
It's almost as if when I select a sort option, the dom is rerendering, and then I'm changing the value of books in state, but that isn't then again causing a re-rendering of the dom.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/open-library-api-p6f0v5?file=/src/App.js)

The code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [sort, setSort] = useState("");
  const API_URL = `https://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=`;

  const sortFn = (books, sortType) => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (sortType === "title") {
      console.log("sorting by title!");
      const sortedBooks = books.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
      setBooks(sortedBooks);
    } else if (sortType === "publishDate") {
      console.log("sorting by date, most recent");
      const sortedBooks = books.sort((a, b) => {
        const dateA = new Date(a.publishDate);
        const dateB = new Date(b.publishDate);
        return dateB - dateA;
      });
      console.log("sorted books:", sortedBooks);
      setBooks(sortedBooks);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const getBooks = async (queryStr) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const {
        data: { docs }
      } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}${queryStr}`);
      // console.log(docs);
      const slice = docs.slice(0, 10);

      const results = slice.map((item) => ({
        title: item.title,
        author: item.author_name[0],
        isbn: item.isbn[0].trim(),
        publishDate: item.publish_date[0]
      }));
      if (sort) {
        sortFn(results, sort);
      } else {
        setBooks(results);
      }

      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (books && sort) sortFn(books, sort);
  }, [sort]);

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const selectChange = (e) => {
    setSort(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input) {
      //must replace whitespace within string with '+' symbol
      const query = input.trim().replace(" ", "+");
      getBooks(query);
    }
    setInput("");
  };

  console.log("books:", books);

  const tiles = books.map((book) => (
    <Book
      key={book.isbn}
      title={book.title}
      author={book.author}
      publishDate={book.publishDate}
      imgURL={`https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/${book.isbn}-M.jpg`}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <input type="text" value={input} onChange={changeHandler} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <select onChange={selectChange}>
        <option value="">Sort by</option>
        <option value="title">Title(A-Z)</option>
        <option value="publishDate">Publish Date</option>
      </select>

      {loading && <div>Loading</div>}

      {!loading && books ? tiles : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you try searching a query, and then after that playing around with the sorting? Because it is sorting but by title when I select date and by date when I select title

Comment: The issue is you're modifying state directly and expecting it to re-render. In React one of the rules is Do Not Modify State Directly. So what you'll need to do is copy the books array, sort it, and return the sorted array to the render. This article should help you out. https://dev.to/ramonak/react-how-to-dynamically-sort-an-array-of-objects-using-the-dropdown-with-react-hooks-195p

Comment: oh my, I forgot the sort method sorts in place. Thank you so much